# Mule EventCorrelator IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: collections, jms, mule, indexoutofboundsexception, aggregator

I use the following flow to aggregate messages coming from the JMS topic.

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint  connector-ref="SonicEng" doc:name="JMS" topic="TESTTOPIC"/>   
<set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="10" doc:name="Property" />      
<set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="#[(String)app.registry.uniqueId]"   doc:name="Property" />
<collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Collection Aggregator" timeout="100"/>   
<expression-component doc:name="Expression">
    app.registry.uniqueId = 1 * app.registry.uniqueId + 1
</expression-component>
<logger message="Message: #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

When the message load is really high, following exception in thrown:

```
event.correlator" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
at org.mule.routing.EventGroup.getMessageCollectionEvent(EventGroup.java:436)
at org.mule.routing.correlation.EventCorrelator$ExpiringGroupMonitoringThread.doRun(EventCorrelator.java:569)
at org.mule.routing.EventProcessingThread.run(EventProcessingThread.java:85)
```

I use Mule EE version 3.4.0. Does anybody have a resolution for this or can it be ignored as it is related to ExpiringGroupMonitoringThread?
Appreciate your response!

I get the following exception in Mule EE 3.4.1. I feel it is related to the same issue.

```
Exception in thread "[appname].monorail.event.correlator"   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.mule.VoidMuleEvent.getFlowConstruct(VoidMuleEvent.java:138)
at org.mule.routing.correlation.EventCorrelator$ExpiringGroupMonitoringThread.doRun(EventCorrelator.java:569)
at org.mule.routing.EventProcessingThread.run(EventProcessingThread.java:85)
```

We loose messages after the correlation aggregator when high volumes of data is used. Can these exceptions relate to the messages being lost?

Comment: The exception is truncated. Is it reported as WARN or ERROR?

Comment: Ahem: `1 * app.registry.uniqueId` ... why?

Comment: It started as Exception in thread "appname". It would have been nice if it was a warning. We are trying to see whether we loose any messages with this exception being thrown.

Comment: I needed a way to set a correlation Id. I used a global variable (uniqueId) to calculate it. I increase it's value by 1 after the correlatior. If I did not use 1 * app.registry.uniqueId, it was evaluated like a String.. then my values were like 11,111, etc.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but I can't leave a comment because I don't have enough reputations. I suggest using `Integer.parseInt(app.registry.uniqueId)` instead of multiplying by 1, in my opinion it looks more readable. Also, shouldn't the object `uniqueId` be accessed like this: `app.registry['uniqueId']` ?

Comment: Thanks! I will try the parseInt. I was able to access the object like app.registry.uniqueId as well. Not sure whether there is a best practice on how to do this.

Comment: @David: I updated my question above with a different exception thrown with Mule 3.4.1.

Comment: If you know for sure `uniqueId` is in the registry then `app.registry.uniqueId` is better.

Comment: Is the initial value of `app.registry.uniqueId` an string? I don't get how it could come  as a string, otherwise? How do you set it?

Comment: Wow you're hitting some pretty intense issues here :( Since you are using EE, better turn to MuleSoft support.

Comment: <global-property name="uniqueId" value="0" doc:name="Global Property" />

Comment: Yeah, this is a string. Use Spring: `<spring:bean name="uniqueId" class="java.lang.Integer"><spring:constructor-arg value="0" /></spring:bean>`

Comment: Thanks David. uniqueID works that way.